# Finite intersection of finite unions of sets (interchanging)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am aware of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878909/question-about-proving-that-a-%EF%AC%81nite-intersection-of-big-unions-is-a-big-union-of) and I want to know if that identity may be written like this $$\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} \left( \bigcup_{\ell=1}^{m_k} C_{k,\ell} \right) = \bigcup_{\ell_1 =1}^{m_1} \bigcup_{\ell_2 =1}^{m_2} \dots \bigcup_{\ell_n =1}^{m_n} \left( \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} C_{k,\ell_k} \right)$$ Here is my attempt for proving it:

Let $ \ x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} \left( \bigcup_{\ell=1}^{m_k} C_{k,\ell} \right)$. Then, for all $ \ k \in \{ 1,...,n \}$, there exists $ \ \ell \in \{ 1,...,m_k \}$, which depends on $k$, such that $ \ x \in C_{k, \ell} \, $. We can say $\ell_1$ for $ \ k=1$, $\ell_2$ for $ \ k=2$, ..., $\ell_n$ for $ \ k=n$. Hence $ \ x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} C_{k,\ell_k} \subset \bigcup_{\ell_1 =1}^{m_1} \bigcup_{\ell_2 =1}^{m_2} \dots \bigcup_{\ell_n =1}^{m_n} \left( \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} C_{k,\ell_k} \right)$.

For the other hand, let $ \ x \in \bigcup_{\ell_1 =1}^{m_1} \bigcup_{\ell_2 =1}^{m_2} \dots \bigcup_{\ell_n =1}^{m_n} \left( \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} C_{k,\ell_k} \right)$. Then there exists $ \ \ell_1 \in \{ 1,...,m_1 \}$, $\ell_2 \in \{ 1,...,m_2 \}$, ..., $\ell_n \in \{ 1,...,m_n \} \ $ such that $ \ x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} C_{k,\ell_k}$. Rewriting, we have that, for all $ \ k \in \{ 1,...,n \}$, there exists $ \ \ell_k \in \{ 1,...,m_k \} \ $ such that $ \ x \in \bigcap_{j=1}^{n} C_{j,\ell_j} \subset C_{k,\ell_k}$. Again, for all $ \ k \in \{ 1,...,n \}$, we have $ \ x \in \bigcup_{\ell_k = 1}^{m_k} C_{k,\ell_k} = \bigcup_{\ell = 1}^{m_k} C_{k,\ell} \, $. Finally, we arrive at $ \ x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} \left( \bigcup_{\ell=1}^{m_k} C_{k,\ell} \right)$.

Is my proof correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks correct to me!
Note that this set identity is the exact analogue of the arithmetic identity
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n} \left( \sum_{\ell=1}^{m_k} x_{k,\ell} \right) = \sum_{\ell_1 =1}^{m_1} \sum_{\ell_2 =1}^{m_2} \dots \sum_{\ell_n =1}^{m_n} \left( \prod_{k=1}^{n} x_{k,\ell_k} \right).
$$

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, it seemed to me that it is all about distributivity, commutativity and associativity.

Answer (score 3):

The formula is correct and I have a rather direct approach for the proof. Have a look at the attached photo.[image]